# How do I access a constructor "this" variable?

Tags: javascript

In my `updateCamera(event)` function, I am trying to access `this.camera` as can be shown in my constructor. Unfortunately, it's undefined in that function, I assume it's a scope issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
export default class Experience {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.camera = new Camera();
        // removed unnecessary stuff
        this.onMouseDrag();
    }

    updateCamera(event) {
        console.log(this.camera); //Prints "undefined" in the console
        this.camera.position.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    }

    onMouseDrag() {
        window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
            window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.updateCamera);
        });
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.updateCamera);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I suppose that before creating the clousure you could define a variable that points to to `this` and since it would be in the closure lexical scope you could access it, e.g. `const that = this`, and then do `that.updateCamera` inside the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this` behaves confusingly in class components.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

When [binding to a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#binding_this_with_prototype_and_static_methods) (your event listener), this is not bound by default. To fix your issue, change `this.updateCamera` to `this.updateCamera.bind(this)` or use an anonymous function (`()=>this.updateCamera()`).

You can also bind this to your functions in your constructor to reduce confusion like this:

```
this.updateCamera = this.updateCamera.bind(this);
```

Comment: Another approach is to actually call the method passing the `event` argument.